# eloquent query condition based on relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
Results(game_id, score) 
Games(start, end, threshold)
```

Given a timestamp:
I want to find all results that belong to a game with a start & end time containing the timestamp time and where the result score is above the game threshold.

I have already managed to query for the time condition, but how can I additionally query for `Results.score > games.threshold`?

```
Results::whereHas('game', function($q) use ($timestamp) {
    $q->where('start', '<=', $timestamp)
      ->where('end', '>=', $timestamp)
})->with('game')->get()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use whereRaw inside whereHas and check if it works:

```
Results::whereHas('game', function($q) use ($timestamp) {
    $q->where('start', '<=', $timestamp)
      ->where('end', '>=', $timestamp)
      ->whereRaw('results.score > games.threshold');
})->with('game')->get();
```